# implement ajax push

Tags: ajax, web, push

This is a very general question. I intend to write a simple SNS which supports the client to send words(like twitters and facebook). Moreover, If there is a reply to someone's twitter, I want the web page to jump out a hint quickly. In this case, I do not want to use polling method. I search the internet and found that AJAX Push is a good way to implement that and I found that something Like APE or Comet. I use LAMP(apache server) architecture on my mac as a localhost. DO I need to change the server to a ajax push supported one? Or I can just implement ajax push on apache. I am really confused about that.